# SYSDATE IN ORACLE APEX FORMS

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-apex

I am working in APEX forms .Here i have table A with the column Date.Here date picker is by default.i want to change the date picker to "SYSDATE" i-e to show the sysdate on the form not to choose it.Please help me out

Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For setting sysdate as default date just open the date settings , 
change the default value type to  PL/SQL Expression and for the value

give (to_char(sysdate,'DD-MON-YYYY'))
it will work.

u can also change the date pickings from the form editing page.

Answer (score 2):

In the item where you want to set sysdate as default

Choose `PL/SQL Expression` and for the value give

```
to_char(sysdate,'DD-MON-YYYY')
```

So you have the sysdate as default value.